# Android ConstraintLayout в коде java задать процент сторон ImageView объекта

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

Всем добрый день. Хочу задать изображению в ImageView размер относительно родительского контейнера в процентах. Но размер картинки не меняется.

```
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
        constraintLayout.setId(View.generateViewId());
 
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();

        ImageView contactUs = new ImageView(this);
        contactUs.setImageResource(R.drawable.rezgoriz);
        contactUs.setId(View.generateViewId());
        constraintLayout.addView(contactUs, 0);

        set.clone(constraintLayout);
        
        set.constrainPercentHeight(constraintLayout.getId(), 20);
        set.constrainPercentWidth(constraintLayout.getId(), 20);

        set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
 
        setContentView(constraintLayout);
```

Как должно получится в итоге

[image: Как должно получится в итоге]

Если кто знает издание, в котором очень подробно разложено как программировать в `ConstraintLayout` с хорошими примерами, тоже буду благодарен.

Answer (score 3):

Я не совсем понимаю зачем вам это делать в коде если тоже самое можно сделать в XML.

- Вы можете добавить `guideline` c параметром `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent`. Пример:

  ```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>
  ```

И после этого использовать этот `guideline` как привязку для других `View`.

- Вы можете использовать параметр `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` и/или `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` для изменения размеров вашей `View`.

  ```
  <Button
      ...
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.25"
      ...
      />
  ```
- Другой способ установить размер в процентах это использовать параметры `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` и/или `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`

  ```
  <Button
      ...
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
      ...
      />
  ```

**UPD**

Исходя из вашего кода, я вижу что у вас получается изменить размер самой. View, но проблема состоит в том, что само изображение не меняется. Вам необходимо уведомить систему что ваша `View` изменилась.

Каждый класс, производный от класса `View`, имеет метод `invalidate()` и `postInvalidate()`. При вызове `invalidate()` он сообщает системе, что текущая `View` изменилась, и ее следует перерисовать как можно скорее. Поскольку этот метод может быть вызван только из вашего `UI Thread`, необходим другой метод, если вы не на `UI Thread` и все еще хотите уведомить систему, что ваша `View` была изменена. Метод `postInvalidate()` уведомляет систему из `не-UI Thread`, и **View** перерисуется при следующем цикле событий в `UI Thread`.

При вызове `invalidate()` ваша `View` перерисуется заново и тем самым перерисут вашу картинку в нужном размере.

**UPD2**

Это метод из документации.

```
    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(@NonNull Drawable dr) {
        if (dr == mDrawable) {
            if (dr != null) {
                // update cached drawable dimensions if they've changed
                final int w = dr.getIntrinsicWidth();
                final int h = dr.getIntrinsicHeight();
                if (w != mDrawableWidth || h != mDrawableHeight) {
                    mDrawableWidth = w;
                    mDrawableHeight = h;
                    // updates the matrix, which is dependent on the bounds
                    configureBounds();
                }
            }
            /* we invalidate the whole view in this case because it's very
             * hard to know where the drawable actually is. This is made
             * complicated because of the offsets and transformations that
             * can be applied. In theory we could get the drawable's bounds
             * and run them through the transformation and offsets, but this
             * is probably not worth the effort.
             */
            invalidate();
        } else {
            super.invalidateDrawable(dr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sergei Buvaka, изображения будут разные при формировании активности. Это проще сделать программно. И при будущих изменениях изображение можно заменить кнопкой с изображением. Так проще масштабировать и вносить изменения.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Думаю это должно помочь

Comment: Sergei Buvaka, к сожалению нет. Если вставить строку set.connect(contactUs.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, constraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 360); то вы увидите, что изображение уйдет вниз. Т.е. всё работает.

Comment: Попробуйте еще этот метод `public void invalidateDrawable(@NonNull Drawable dr)`

Comment: Sergei Buvaka, зачем invalidateDrawable? Суть в том, что я программно делаю нужный мне масштаб ImageView и относительно него добавляю остальные элементы. Как в RelativeLayout. И весь интерфейс автоматически масштабируется. Мне не понятно, где я не понимаю логики. Там другие команды не дает подставить в set. И соответственно все должно делаться через ConstraintLayout.

Comment: если меняется размер View, но не меняется размер самого изображения, то изображение показывается куском большего вида. Столкнулся с этим давеча. Так что вообще никакие ваши ответы не подходят.